# How to use break-continue inside for-loop when row/column values changes inside the database?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, break, continue

In the given data set I need to multiply values from different blocks with each other.

**I want to inject break-continue within for loop** but the examples I have looked so far isn't quite helping. Actually, this data is just a part of the big data so I need some explanation on how - why break-continue works.

`So,for X(set) I have to multiply: 0.25*0.1*0.83 (since they belong to same block`

```
block   X_set
2480    0.25
2480    0.1
2480    0.083
2651    0.43
2651    0.11
2651    0.23
```

My code is as follows:

```
test_q = open("test_question.txt", "r+")
header = test_q.readline()
data_q = test_q.read().rstrip("\n")

product=1.0
value_list = []

row = data_q.split("\n")

for line in row:
    block = line.split("\t")
    X_list = block[1].split()
    X_value = float(block[1])
    value_list = value_list + X_list
    product = product*X_value

print(value_list)
print(product)
```

The result is:

```
['0.25', '0.1', '0.083', '0.43', '0.11', '0.23']
2.2573925000000003e-05
```

But, in the print I want

```
['0.25', '0.1', '0.083']
0.0002075

['0.43', '0.11', '0.23']
0.010879
```

**So, how to inject the break and continue function within this for-loop?**

- I don't want to use a fixed value for blocks since this is a long file and the block value will change.
- Also, the row with same block values may not be next to each other.
- Also, i don't need solution on pandas since this is just a part of big file which is exclusive mined using for-if-else loop.

Thanks much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `break` nor `continue`, all you have to do is:

#1 keep track of current block

#2 collect data for the current block

#3 when the block change, process current collected data

#4 after the loop end, repeat point #3

It's a quite common pattern FWIW.

Example:

```
import csv
import operator

# for test
from StringIO import StringIO

dat = """
block\tX_set
2480\t0.25
2480\t0.1
2480\t0.083
2651\t0.43
2651\t0.11
2651\t0.23
"""
f = StringIO(dat.strip())
f.seek(0)

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
header = reader.next()
current = None
values = []
results = []

for key, val in reader:
    # is this a new block ?
    if key != current:
        # ok, do we have values ?
        if values:
            # let's compute our product for collected values
            #print block
            #print reduce(operator.mul, map(float, blockvals))
            # and collect them for later use
            results.append((values, reduce(operator.mul, map(float, values))))
        # reset the values collector for the block
        values = []
        # and the current block so we can detect next change
        current = key

    # in all cases we want to collect data for this block
    values.append(val)

# handle the last block
if values:
    results.append((values, reduce(operator.mul, map(float, values))))


# and now display our results:
for blockvals, product in results:
    print blockvals
    print product
```

which yields:

```
['0.25', '0.1', '0.083']
0.002075
['0.43', '0.11', '0.23']
0.010879
```

Comment: Thanks @burno. But, looks like the StringIO has changed in python 3.6 which I am using. Also, tried to modify the code a little bit but not successful until not. The other problem is most of the data mining is already done using for-if-else. I will have to find a way to fit this is. At the mean time can you please input something to the solution I am trying to use. See below.

Comment: You don't need the `StringIO` part, it was just as part of the example, to avoid a dependancy on an external file. Ditto for the use of the `csv` module - that's what you *should* use to parse csv (or in your case tsv) files, but you can still do manual parsing instead. The useful part is the use of `current` to keep track of "block change" and the use of `values` to collect values for the current block and process them at block change (and one last time after the loop). This is the part you have to retrofit in your existing code.

Comment: HI bruno: This kind of looping is very new to me and I have just begun using programming coming from biology background. Could you please add more details to what is happening at each step. Also, I see that reduce isn't defined and I am getting error messages like "reduce isn't defined" too.

Comment: I just realized that `reduce` function has changed to `functools` in python 3. I changed that but still getting error: `results.append((values, functools(operator.mul, map(float, values))))`
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

Comment: `functools` is the module, not the function. You want `functools.reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is way easier using the `groupby()` function, otherwise if you're sure you won't have too many blocks, use a dictionary.

If this is to solve a programming exercise and you're guaranteed to have blocks in a sequence, keep a partial sum of the current block and if you encounter a new block, print the sum and then reset it to 0.